# Delphi, RESTClient, CouchDB - HEAD Method

Tags: rest, delphi, http-headers, couchdb

I am using REST component in Delphi Seattle.

I would like to send HEAD method to server for check the document exist in data base, and get the revision number.

Can I do this by used REST component ?

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/REST_Client_Library

Comment: What trouble did you encounter when you tried?

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/REST.Client.TRESTRequest.Method
There isn't rmHEAD in enumerator type.

Comment: Then it looks like the answer's *no*. Was that all you needed to know?